# When calling a specific url, do not give full media url in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After changing image to url, I am giving it to API. However, even though serialization has been carried out through the same serializer, when a request is sent to a particular url, it is transferred in the form of media/image_name instead of 127.0.0.1:8000/media/image_name. I can't find the cause of this. Can you help me find the cause by looking at my code?

views.py

```
class ReadAllListPostView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

class ReadCommentView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all().order_by('pk')

    def list (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)
        post.view_count = post.view_count + 1
        post.save(update_fields=('view_count', ))

        comments = self.queryset.filter(post=postId)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(comments, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

feed\serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    owner = userProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    like_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    images = ImageSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    liked_people = LikeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    tag = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), allow_null=True, required=False)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'content', 'view_count', 'images', 'like_count', 'comment_count', 'liked_people', 'tag', 'created_at', 'comments')

    def create (self, validated_data) :
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data, created_at=str(datetime.now().astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()))
        
        for i in range(1, 6) :
            image_data = images_data.get(F'image{i}')

            if image_data is None :
                break

            Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)

        return post

    def to_representation (self, instance) :
        data = super().to_representation(instance)

        images = data.pop('images')
        liked_people = data.pop('liked_people')
        comments = data.pop('comments')

        images_array = [image.get('image') for image in images]
        liked_people_array = [liked_person.get('liked_people') for liked_person in liked_people]
        comments_array = [comment for comment in comments]

        if comments_array != [] :
            if len(comments_array) == 1 or len(comments_array) == 2:
                data.update({'image_urls': images_array, 'liked_people': liked_people_array, 'comment_preview': comments_array})

            else :
                comments_preview_array = []

                for i in range(2) :
                    random_comment = random.choice(comments_array)
                    comments_array.remove(random_comment)
                    comments_preview_array.append(random_comment)

                data.update({'image_urls': images_array, 'liked_people': liked_people_array, 'comment_preview': comments_preview_array})
                    
        else :
            data.update({'image_urls': images_array, 'liked_people': liked_people_array})

        return data
```

api\serializers.py

```
class userProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    following = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta :
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'username', 'image', 'following', 'followers']

    def get_following (self, obj) :
        serializer = FollowingSerializer(obj.following.all(), many=True).data
        return len(serializer)

    def get_followers (self, obj) :
        serializer = FollowersSerializer(obj.followers.all(), many=True).data
        return len(serializer)
```

If I ask you to see the comments on post 1 (feed/post/1/comments)

```
[
    {
        "comment_id": 1,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "dsgsdg",
            "username": "sdgdsg",
            "image": "/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "content": "nice to meet you",
        "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:35:39+09:00"
    },
    {
        "comment_id": 2,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "dsgdsf",
            "username": "dsgdsgf",
            "image": "/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "content": "nice to meet yall",
        "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:48:51+09:00"
    },
    {
        "comment_id": 3,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "dsgdsg",
            "username": "dsgsdg",
            "image": "/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "content": "gang gnagn",
        "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:49:06+09:00"
    },
    {
        "comment_id": 4,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "sdgsdfg",
            "username": "dsgsd",
            "image": "/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "content": "yrdy",
        "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:54:21+09:00"
    }
]
```

If the base url of the image is truncated as follows but the entire post is requested (feed/post/all)

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "safa",
            "username": "safasd",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "title": "hi",
        "content": "sadfsad",
        "view_count": 1,
        "like_count": 1,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "tag": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-21T21:55:29+09:00",
        "image_urls": [],
        "liked_people": [
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "sadfa",
            "username": "asdfa",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "title": "hi",
        "content": "sdafadf",
        "view_count": 1,
        "like_count": 1,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "tag": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-20T20:45:50+09:00",
        "image_urls": [],
        "liked_people": [
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "sadfas",
            "username": "sadfasdf",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
            "following": 0,
            "followers": 0
        },
        "title": "hello",
        "content": "nice to meet you",
        "view_count": 16,
        "like_count": 2,
        "comment_count": 4,
        "tag": [
            "안녕 쟈기"
        ],
        "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:20:17+09:00",
        "image_urls": [],
        "liked_people": [
            2,
            1
        ],
        "comment_preview": [
            {
                "comment_id": 2,
                "owner": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "email": "safasd",
                    "username": "safasfd",
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
                    "following": 0,
                    "followers": 0
                },
                "content": "nice to meet yall",
                "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:48:51+09:00"
            },
            {
                "comment_id": 4,
                "owner": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "email": "safad",
                    "username": "sadfas",
                    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-2_%EA%B2%8C%EC%8B%9C%EB%AC%BC.jpg",
                    "following": 0,
                    "followers": 0
                },
                "content": "safasd",
                "created_at": "2020-10-19T20:54:21+09:00"
            }
        ]
```

Like this, media url comes full.

Comment: the first response is your actual response and the second response is what you wanted as a response? Am I correct?

Comment: Both the first and second coming responses are actually coming. I mean most url get a second response, but only a few url get the first. I wonder why the first response is coming and would like to unify all url into the second response.

Comment: I think this will depend on which Serializers are declared in the View which maps to `feed/post/1/comments` vs the View which maps to `feed/post/all` - can you post your Views which are mapped to these URLs?

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I add it

Comment: So is the problem that one view uses `CommentSerializer` and the other `PostSerializer`?

Comment: The problem occurs in the view using the commentserializer, and the view using the postserializer does not.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is occurred because your serializer gets context in some cases, and in other cases it does not.

When serializer gets request in context, it tries to build absolute url to media `http://...` . When it doesn't get request in context, then it will just build relative url `/media/`.

You have two options:

1. Provide all your serializers with request in context.
2. Remove request context from some serialises.

To remove context passed to serializers in your ViewSets, you can just redeclare `get_serializer_context` method:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {}
```